# Where to store my strings in a plain ruby project

Tags: ruby

i'm coding with Rails since 2 years. I noticed that I had some gaps in pure ruby and decided to build a side project in plain ruby.
My project is basically a discord bot and i'm wondering what's the best way to store some data.

My bot use a method to ask questions and await input from user, all questions data are stored in a object with this structure:

```rb
QUESTIONS = {
  title1: {
    content: 'string',
    validator: /regex/,
    invalid_input_message: 'string'
  },
  title2: {
    content: 'string',
    validator: /regex/,
    invalid_input_message: 'string'
  },
  # ...
}
```

Since i will implement a lot of question, i don't want to store this object in my class file. Inspired by i18n, my first intention was to use a yaml file, but i have regex too not only string. Moreover, since i would have to load my YAML into a ruby object, i was wondering if i could just store my object in a ruby file and import it to my Bot class.

Would it be to store my object in a ruby file or should i use YAML ? And how to deal with this regex if i go for YAML ?

thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML allows storing regexp too, when you need to tell the parser to allow parsing `Regexp`.

```
require 'yaml'

yaml = <<~YAML
  string: Hallo World
  regexp: !ruby/regexp /^regexp/
YAML

hash = YAML.load(yaml, permitted_classes: [Regexp])

hash['string']
#=> "Hallo World"

hash['regexp']
#=> /^regexp/
hash['regexp'].class
#=> Regexp
```